# How to call a function in a settings form from my main form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms in my project,

1. Main Form
2. Settings form

I need to call a method from the main form for an event in the settings form. My main form has the splash screen (in the constructor) so I could not create an instance of the main form to call the method.

Is there any way to call the function without calling the main form's constructor? Or is there any other way I can implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can send the Main form to the Settings form as a constructor argument (assuming Settings is called from Main).

A better method would be to send a `Func<...>` or `Action<...>` to the Settings form and let it call that instead.

```
...

public Settings(Action<int> myAction)
{  
    _myAction = myAction;
}


...
    _myAction(5);

...
```

Comment: I am new to this C# world. Can you please explain a bit further?? Action/Function denotes my method in main form? and myAction is the instance of main form? pls help

Comment: @Deepa:  `myAction` is the method you want the Settings form to call.  It's akin to a function pointer in C, if that's your background.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a singleton class that holds your common functions that you need to call from your forms.

Some info on Singletons in c#
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In your Main Form keep the reference to the instance of SettingForm.

```
SettingsForm mySettingsForm;

public MainForm(SettingsForm settingsForm)
{
    _mySettingsForm = settingsForm;
}

private void CallSettingsFormMethods()
{
   _mySettingsForm.CallAnyPublicMethod();
}
```

When creating the MainForm instance, create an instance of SettingsForm and pass it to the MainForm. SettingsForm won't be visible unless you call Show or ShowDialog methods.

```
SettingsForm settingsForm = new SettingsForm();
MainForm myMainForm = new MainForm(settingsForm);
myMainForm.Show();
```